# SQL Update with Subquery Null Conditional

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to run a query akin to the following.  I'm basically trying to change the format of the updated text conditionally.  I need some help as I've tried this a few different ways without success.  Thanks in advance.

```
UPDATE bL SET 
bL.[QUANTITY] = bL.[QUANTITY] + 2,
bL.[SERIAL_NUMBERS] = 
    (
      CASE WHEN bL.[SERIAL_NUMBERS] IS NOT NULL 
      THEN ISNULL(bL.[SERIAL_NUMBERS], '') + 'EOSB7U310007; EOSB7U310022' 
      ELSE bL.[SERIAL_NUMBERS] + '; EOSB7U310007; EOSB7U310022'
    ) 
 FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_BOXES_LINES] AS bL 
 LEFT JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_BOXES] AS bO 
 ON bL.[AOF_BOXES_ID] = bO.[ID] 
 WHERE bO.[SELECTED] = 'True'
```

Comment: Remove the `select` before `case when`.

Comment: Also, concatenating a `null` to a string will result in `null`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Sorry, I forgot to add that I ISNULL() given that the cell value is null.

Comment: Checking the `bO.[SELECTED] = 'True'` will change your `Left Join` to an `Inner Join`.

Comment: @GSerg The consistent problem that I run in to when testing is `Incorrect syntax near ')'.` I'm still running into this with your change.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Could you explain?

Comment: You need an `END` in the `Case statement`

Comment: @Jaberwocky. Since you aren't checking ISNull(bO.[SELECTED],'') = 'True'. You are implicitly looking for bO.[SELECTED] = 'True'. Where null values won't get evaluated.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Wow, how did I miss that...  This goes to show ya, a second set of eyes when you're tired of looking at something is ALWAYS beneficial :D

Comment: @WEI_DBA If you want to put your answer up I'll vote it up.

Comment: Zohar's shortened version will probably work best for you. Give that a shot.

Answer (score 2):

So, putting all the comments I found correct together in a single answer, your code should probably look like this:

```
UPDATE bL SET 
bL.[QUANTITY] = bL.[QUANTITY] + 2,
bL.[SERIAL_NUMBERS] = 
    (
      CASE WHEN bL.[SERIAL_NUMBERS] IS NULL 
      THEN 'EOSB7U310007; EOSB7U310022' 
      ELSE bL.[SERIAL_NUMBERS] + '; EOSB7U310007; EOSB7U310022'
      END
    ) 
 FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_BOXES_LINES] AS bL 
 LEFT JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_BOXES] AS bO 
 ON bL.[AOF_BOXES_ID] = bO.[ID] 
 AND bO.[SELECTED] = 'True'
```

However it can be shorten - like this:

```
UPDATE bL SET 
bL.[QUANTITY] = bL.[QUANTITY] + 2,
bL.[SERIAL_NUMBERS] = ISNULL(bL.[SERIAL_NUMBERS] + '; ', '') + 'EOSB7U310007; EOSB7U310022'
 FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_BOXES_LINES] AS bL 
 LEFT JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_BOXES] AS bO 
 ON bL.[AOF_BOXES_ID] = bO.[ID] 
 AND bO.[SELECTED] = 'True'
```

This is because it the value of `bL.[SERIAL_NUMBERS]` is null then the concatenation of it with `;` will also be null.

Notes:

- I've moved `bO.[SELECTED] = 'True'` from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause. This is because when using a left join, all the conditions on the right table should be on the `ON` clause, otherwise the join is turned into an inner join.
- Seems like you are using the `bL.[SERIAL_NUMBERS]` column to store multiple values. This is a big mistake in 99.9999% of the cases.
  Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why.

Comment: Noted.  The customer designed their system this way, I am just adapting and integrating with them :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `SELECT` and you have to `END` your `CASE` statement.

```
UPDATE  bL
SET     bL.[QUANTITY] = bL.[QUANTITY] + 2
      , bL.[SERIAL_NUMBERS] = ( CASE WHEN bL.[SERIAL_NUMBERS] IS NOT NULL 
                                     THEN ISNULL(bL.[SERIAL_NUMBERS] , '') + 'EOSB7U310007; EOSB7U310022'
                                     ELSE bL.[SERIAL_NUMBERS] + '; EOSB7U310007; EOSB7U310022'
                                END )
FROM    [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_BOXES_LINES] AS bL
LEFT JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_MECHUAT].[dbo].[AOF_BOXES] AS bO ON bL.[AOF_BOXES_ID] = bO.[ID]
WHERE   bO.[SELECTED] = 'True';
```